# Optimization with solver 'trust-constr'

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

how can I use the solver 'trust-constr only with linear inequality constraints?
my constraints is c(x)>0 & c(x)=g(x,teta)-ymin
how can I use only this linear inequality constraints for solver 'trust-constr' ?

the python code for c(x) constraint is doing interpolation like below:

```
#pressure_cons_val is ymin
#input_val is teta

input_val = (BHP, GOR, WC, GLR, LR)
#function do_interpolation is written
interpol=self.file.do_interpolation(0)
res=interpol(input_val) #g(x,teta)
cons=res-pressure_cons_val
```

Comment: Hello, please try to provide a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

You can find details about the solver here:

- [optimize.minimize-trustconstr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-trustconstr.html)

If the constraint is linear in one or more variable, you need to wrap it into the SciPy's [LinearConstraint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint.html#scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint) object.

I cannot help you better until I'm able to read and understand your code (what are the input variables, the objective function and the constraint(s), see also the general form of [a continuous minimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem#Continuous_optimization_problem)).